# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2'

Tags: php, xampp

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried:
>   E:\phpXampp\php\ext\gd2 (The specified module could not be found.),
>   E:\phpXampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: E:\phpXampp\php\ext\gettext
>   (The specified module could not be found.),
>   E:\phpXampp\php\ext\php_gettext.dl l (The specified module could not
>   be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

I have this problem installing laravel. Actual link is

`E:\XAMPPL\php\ext\gettext` while it show `E:\phpXampp\php\ext\gettext` in warning.

How to change the path?

Comment: run this code `sudo apt-get install php7.gd2`

Comment: I have already php 7.3.1 . Do I need to install other version?

Comment: update the library

Answer (score 3):

Go to you php installation folder - I'm guessing this is `E:\XAMPPL\php\`. Open and edit the php.ini file there.

Look for the line containing `extension_dir`. This is used by php to locate your extensions. Edit this line to:

```
extension_dir = "E:\XAMPPL\php\ext"
```

This should solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could just edit it to:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

They both refer to the same path.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled composer and then installed latest composer setup and restarted my PC. And it Worked.